# como agregar un separador en un campo varchar sql server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, date, tablas, subconsultas

tengo una tabla con miles de registros y existe un campo de fechas que esta creada como varchar y tiene el siguiente formato

```
FECHA
28122019
12032014
21062022
08012017
10112023
```

quisiera poder agregar un separador y que quedara mas o menos asi

```
28/12/2019
12/03/2014
21/06/2022
08/01/2017
10/11/2023
```

sin perder la propiedad de varchar, aclaro que no tengo acceso a modicar los campos, para convertir a date como deberia ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `STUFF()` puede ser útil en este caso

```
select FECHA
    ,  stuff(stuff(FECHA, 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/') as nuevaFECHA
from Tabla
where FECHA not like '%/%'
```

Comment: Gracias @Xabi la use y me funcionó muy bien

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [SUBSTRING](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_substring.asp) y vas concatenando las partes hasta forma el formato requerido

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(fecha, 1, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(fecha, 3, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(fecha, 5, 4) AS fechaConFormato from Tabla;
```